# Fluidity with Cards of Different Lengths

Tags: html, css

I've been using a card style for [a website I've been designing](http://i.imgur.com/E7YvDIh.png). As you can see, it is made of individual cards to separate the information and make the fact that it is separate obvious.

My problem is that the only way I knew off the top of my head to achieve this to an *alright* standard, was to create two `div` elements inside of another two.

Something like this:

```
<div id="container-one" align="center">
<div id="container-two">

    <div class="container-two-left" align="center">
    </div>

    <div class="container-two-right" align="center">
    </div>

</div>
```

Although they resize to something, again, *alright* for computers; the fluidity of it doesn't stay consistent for smaller, mobile devices. The mobile browser instead chooses to just show the whole site as if zoomed out - which, yeah, works, but isn't ideal when I want text to be big enough to just glance at.

The problem I seem to be having is that I can `float: left;` all I want, but as soon as one card becomes bigger, it doesn't retain the same one-after-the-other style, as shown in the image above (using the two containers for left and right).

Is there a better way to handle the placement of those cards?

Comment: You can make use of bootstrap. Bootstrap is specially designed for such responsive requirements. You can design your website such that how you want to render it on different devices or devices with different sizes. Here is the link for everything related to bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @SandeepKushwah Bootstrap was designed for lazy people.

Comment: Or you can not use bootstrap and just write CSS to do what bootstrap does.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: I'm not so sure about that, I'm not lazy, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy I get tired of hearing people say how great bootstrap is, how it does everything and how it should solve every ones issues. it is a good tool to know, but it should be used as a tool. Knowing fluid design should come first. and to add to it all pages I build without bootstrap average about twice as fast with half the data usage.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith lol :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a layout like this using media queries, that way at phone sizes you will be able to make your divs larger and appear to be bigger on the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/e9ypqy5t/11/

```
#container-one{width: 100%; height: 1200px; background-color: lightblue;}
#container-two{width: 800px; height: calc(100% - 6px); border-style: solid; border-color: red;}
.container-two-left{width: calc(50% - 6px); height: 50px; border-style: solid; border-color: green; float: left; margin-top: 10px;}
.container-two-right{width: calc(50% - 6px); height: 50px; border-style: solid; border-color: orange; float: left; margin-top: 10px;}

@media (max-width: 900px){
    #container-two{width: calc(100% - 12px);}
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
    .container-two-left{width: calc(100% - 6px);}
    .container-two-right{width: calc(100% - 6px)}

}
```

Comment: The only error that needs to be corrected is that the content of both columns collide when the viewport is too small to have them side-by-side.

Comment: @JoshCrowe What do you mean collide?

Comment: The columns in your reply work to a great extent; they seperate the content properly (see here http://i.imgur.com/uNuCBLe.png). When the viewport becomes small enough (say, a mobile device), It collides. You can see the right column's content under or over the top of the left's (see here http://i.imgur.com/lKy3SHd.png )

Comment: @JoshCrowe My answer was just a shell, it seems that you have other issues now. Send me a fiddle if you want me to take a look.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Column height was stuck on `80px`, I set it to `auto` and it wrapped around my elements inside instead.

Comment: @Crowes Good to hear, I was going to take a look on my lunch break. glad you found it

Comment: No problem. Thanks for all your help! I nearly went to Bootstrap too.. god forbid.

Comment: Hey @Adam Buchanan Smith, sorry to bother, but can this be adapted for 3 columns?