# How can I have a <div> layout split into three columns with rows in the middle column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a `<div>` layout to split into rows. I can probably accomplish this with an HTML table but this design needs to be fluid so that it can be viewed on mobile devices. I've looked into making a responsive HTML table and that doesn't seem like a good solution.

So in the "What I want" part of the picture, I want columns ONE and SEVEN to automatically expand to the total height of rows THREE through SIX. Columns ONE and SEVEN will be empty, rows THREE, FIVE, and SIX will have the text of varying length and row FOUR will have an image of `width: 1020px` and `height: 1024px`.

The total width of rows THREE through SIX should be 80% of the screen width and the width of columns ONE and SEVEN should each be 10% of the screen width.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6. Below is the code for the "what I'm getting" part of the picture and its CSS.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.two {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
.three {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: orange;
}
.four {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: purple;
}
.five {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
.six {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: green;
}
.seven {
    display: inline;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper container-fluid">
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">THREE</div>
        <div class="four">FOUR</div>
        <div class="five">FIVE</div>
        <div class="six">SIX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="seven">SEVEN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap, given the tag is in the question, and you have a default class from bootstrap `container-fluid`, then you just need to use the already defined bootstrap classes `.row`/`col-*-*` and setting `display:flex` in `.row`

```css
.row {
  display: flex
}
.one {
  background: blue;
}
.three {
  background: orange;
}
.four {
  background: purple;
}
.five {
  background: yellow;
}
.six {
  background: green;
}
.seven {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 one">ONE</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 two">
      <div class="three">THREE</div>
      <div class="four">FOUR</div>
      <div class="five">FIVE</div>
      <div class="six">SIX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 seven">SEVEN</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flex` or `table` `display` here:
(added a break points at around 600-720px for flex & 660px for table version)

run snippet in full page mode to see behavior

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .one {
   background: blue;
 }
 .two {
   width: 80%;
 }
 .three {
   background: orange;
 }
 .four {
   background: purple;
 }
 .five {
   background: yellow;
 }
 .six {
   background: green;
 }
 .seven {

   background: red;
 }
/* FLEX*/
 .flex  {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   }
.flex>div {flex:1 1 10%}
.flex .two {
  min-width:600px;
  max-width:100%;
  flex:1 1 80%
  }
/* TABLE*/
 .table {
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
 }
 .table> div{
   display: table-cell;
 }
@media (max-width : 660px ) {
  .table > div {display:block;width:100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper container-fluid flex">
    <div class="one">ONE</div>

    <div class="two">
      <div class="three">THREE</div>
      <div class="four">FOUR</div>
      <div class="five">FIVE</div>
      <div class="six">SIX</div>
    </div>

    <div class="seven">SEVEN</div>
  </div>
 
<hr/>


  <div class="wrapper container-fluid table">
    <div class="one">ONE</div>

    <div class="two">
      <div class="three">THREE</div>
      <div class="four">FOUR</div>
      <div class="five">FIVE</div>
      <div class="six">SIX</div>
    </div>

    <div class="seven">SEVEN</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Both flex and table work but bootstrap `.row/col-*-*` is easier to work with

Comment: @MichaelSwartz if you are using bootstrap,  I never do cause it always need to be override if your design is not a "bootstrap" design/theme ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a long time, i've employed the usage of media queries.

```
.container {
    margin: 10%;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        width: calc(100% - 12px);
    }
}
.column {
    width: calc(45% - 6px);
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: calc(100% - 6px);
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

You can also do this with `divs` (3 columns) by changing the `calc` equation in `.column` to `((100% / 3) - 6px)`. For every new column, update the divison. Just note they get smaller along the way.

---

Credit to @Adam Buchanan Smith

[Fluidity with Cards of Different Lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659541/fluidity-with-cards-of-different-lengths)